# QtCreator: How do I register "override" and "final" as a keyword?

Tags: c++, qt-creator, keyword

C++11 (or C++0x) introduces the *override* and *final* keywords to C++. Great stuff, and we're gonna use them to make our code better. BUT, while the MS Visual-C++ 2010 compiler handles the keywords perfectly, QtCreator (my IDE of choice) is totally confused by them. *override* methods are marked as errors, and --- much worse --- all code-navigational functionality or symbolic code search is completely screwed. :(

So much for my problem. My question as above: How can I teach QtCreator to recognize *override* and *final* as keywords?

Thanks!
--Robin

PS: I use QtCreator 2.3, newest stable version AFAIK. Compiler is MSVC2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you'll need to wait until they release it to support C++11. Recompiling it would not be a good option as you will need to take care of everything (lexical, symbol table) by changing the grammar of the language by introducing two new keywords.

Comment: Yes, writing a patch for QtCreator is not what I wanted to do. So, this is not exactly the answer I was looking for, but still it is the answer. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
 #if __GNUC__*100 + __GNUC_MINOR__ < 40700
  #define override
  #define final
 #endif //GCC version
#else //defined GNUC
 #ifdef _MSC_VER
  #if _MSC_VER < 1600
   #define override
   #define final
  #else //MS version
   #error "UNKNOWN COMPILER"
  #endif //MS version
 #endif //MS defined
#endif //defined GNUC
```

This will cause it to ignore those two words entirely

Comment: and you specified MSVC compiler.  Give me a sec

Comment: That will fix the syntax highlighting but you have to include it everywhere, which is a pain.

Comment: Yeah, the problem with that is that it actually kills any benefit you get from using _override_ and _final_: the compiler won't handle them any longer and won't warn me of mistakes. Though this is pretty close to what I'm doing right now, except I put it all in `#ifdef DEBUG`...

Comment: Oh, I misread the problem.  The compiler is handling them correctly, but the IDE is not.  Thats... a totally different problem. One to which I have NO idea what the answer is.

Comment: This isn't quite right. You can use `-std=c++03` with modern _gcc_ for some legacy code for instance. If this legacy code uses your nice modern cross-version headers, it's all going to end in tears. Maybe test the value of `__cplusplus` in _gcc_ > 4.7?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
#if __cplusplus < 201103L
    #define override
#endif
```

You then have to make sure you compile in C++-11 mode (in GCC that would be "-std=c++11"). It's usually a good idea to have a "config.h" header that you then include everywhere for exactly this kind of stuff. With some well crafted macros, you can assure that your code also builds with older compilers. Unless you absolutely rely on a specific feature that can't be #if'ed away.